# WMI Error 0x800706BA on some servers in different domain

Tags: powershell, wmi

When trying wmi query I am getting error **0x800706BA ** from powershell, while am able to run wmi query to another servers. Problem is that target server is in different domain than client server, however user of one domain may login to server in another domain. I am domain administrator and telnet on port 135 is working and firewall on target machine is disabled.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Error 800706BA is most likely a firewall RPC blocking port issue on the user PC. Ensure the user machine is set to be trusted for delegation.

Error Codes: 
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_800706BA.htm

VBS Trusted delegation: 
1. (Article) http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Miscellaneous/Q_21372685.html 
2. (Reference) http://support.microsoft.com/?id=305144 
3. (Example) http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/bbfadc43-f843-4c3f-87db-fe038c6416db/

Hope this helps ;)